# How to change the opacity of a background colour - BG-INFO Opacity

Tags: background-color, opacity

I have checked the forum and other forums

I have this in my code. However, I need to change the opacity to 50%. I can't for the life in me figure out what to do. Please could you help?

```
<a class="p-2 mb-2 bg-info text-white>
```

Many thanks

Luke

Answer (score 0):

Opacity takes the value from 0 to 1. Not percentage.

You can add a class to your object as:

```
<a class="p-2 mb-2 bg-info text-white half-opacity" >
```

Then you can define the CSS class as:

```
half-opacity {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```